# Where is the jar file for EJB3 annotations for JBoss 5?

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0

This should be simple, but I'm at a complete loss.

I'm working through a tutorial for setting up some MBeans in JBoss 5.0. It has an example like this:

```
@Remote
public interface Calculator {
    public double getInterestRate();

    public double calculateTotalInterest(double presentValue, int years);

    public double calculateFutureValue(double presentValue, int years);
}
```

I'm trying to find the jar file that contains the data for the @Remote annotation, and I cannot seem to find which jar file I need. A google search gives me little to nothing that seems to apply to JBoss **5.0**. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's smuggled away inside `common/lib/jboss-javaee.jar`, along with the rest of the JavaEE API. This JAR is for use by the JBoss server.

Another copy is kept inside `client/jboss-javaee.jar`, for use by clients.

Both are copies of the same classes.

Comment: Thank you, Skaffman. That did the trick. You saved me much searching.

Answer (score 1):

And if you are in a similar situation in future, go to www.findjar.com, type in the name of the class, and the search engine would find the jar for you. That website has served me countless times.